# Update a textarea by another textarea while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to update a textarea by another textarea while the user is typing?

This is how I tried to achieve this. But did not work.

```
.on("click blur keyup", "input.fTypex", function() {
            $('#textarea1').val($('#textarea2').val());
        });
```

Comment: There is a reason why SO tells you to not only link to jsfiddle. Bypassing this error message by adding a space in the link does not solve that problem. You should always put the relevant part of you code (js and html) with the question. And you should not ask two complete different questions in one.

Comment: @t.niese: I've edited my post with no Fiddles and limited to a single question.

Comment: Then my comment was misleading. A jsfiddle in your question is a great thing as people that want to answer can just click an it to play around with the code. But you always should also include the relevant code parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sweet & short code for you -

eg.

**html**

```
<textarea id="textarea1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
```

**js code-**

```
 $("#textarea1").keyup(function(){
          $('#textarea2').val(this.value);
  });
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/j90zyvnv/

User demand - with using 'on' event js code -

```
 $("#textarea1").on('keyup',function(){
          $('#textarea2').val(this.value);
   });
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/j90zyvnv/1/

Comment: beautiful! `$('#textarea2').val(this.value)` syntax is almost similar to mine. How would you write it using `.on("keyup", function() {`?

Comment: @Fergoso thanks dude! you can write using `$("#textarea1").on('keyup',function(){` see - [http://jsfiddle.net/j90zyvnv/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/j90zyvnv/1/)

Comment: What do you mean by `User demand`?  `$("#textarea1").keyup(callback)` is just a shortcut for  `$("#textarea1").on('keyup', callback)`, there is no difference between them.

Comment: @t.niese actually sir user want js code using `on' event so i was updated my answer. but your right both are same!!

Comment: @RohitSutharMumbai sorry didn't got that it was about the first comment. To me `User` was somthing like `User of the form/textarea` :D

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue:

```
$('#txt1').keyup(function(){
    $('#txt2').html($('#txt1').val());
});
```

For your second issue, just use `float:left` in `style`:

```
<input type="button" style="float:left" />  <select style="float:left"></select>
```

Comment: You answered just a part of the question, how should it then answer the full question?

Comment: Hi t.niese
I answered partly because another one is already answered by Manish sharma. You can follow that

Comment: This is the code for first part:
$('#txt1').keyup(function(){
    $('#txt2').html($('#txt1').val());
});

Comment: The OP can accept only one answer and as you say `Please mark as answer if it answers your question`, you need to give a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

**to update a textarea by another textarea while the user is typing**

using JQuery

```
$("#textBox1").keyup(function(){
     $('#textBox2').val(this.value);
});
```

**to update a textarea when another textarea changing.(by user or system)**

Using Jquery

```
$("#textBox1").change(function(){
     $('#textBox2').val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: @Fergoso try this using jquery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679004/update-a-textarea-by-another-textarea-while-typing/25679269#25679269

Comment: A _C#_ answer to a js/html question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give float left in button

```
<button id="bld_1" type="button" class="btn" style="float:left">Flag</button>
```

add in css

```
 button.btn{
  float:left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$('#textarea2').keyup(function(){
    $('#textarea1').html($('#textarea2').val());
});
```